# Intrupt Incoming call in android and display my custome UI

Tags: android, phone-call

How to intrupt incomin call and display custom ui.
i am trying my code but default dialer is open every time.
below is my code -

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Log.d("CallReceiver","IncomingBroadcastReceiver: onReceive: ");

                String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                Log.d("CallReceiver","IncomingBroadcastReceiver: onReceive: " + state);
                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){

                    Intent i = new Intent(context, IncomingCallActivity.class);
                    i.putExtras(intent);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
}
```

how to fix this issue.Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For handler incoming call you better using CallStateListener

```html
 private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
  @Override
  public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
      switch (state) {
          case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
           Intent i = new Intent(context, IncomingCallActivity.class);
                    i.putExtras(intent);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(i);
          break;
      }
  }
```

}

This requires android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission and init your listener in onCreate()

```html
CallStateListener phoneListener = new CallStateListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,i am using your code but how to get context in phone listener.